# Write a text file named copy_success.txt with content "Copy done"

Tags: python

I need to write a text file named copy_success.txt with content "Copy done" present in  a directory named "dir",can anyone suggest how to do that?

Comment: `with open('dir/copy_success.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('Copy done')`

Comment: I get an error     with open('dir/copy_success.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('Copy done'
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dir/copy_success.txt'

Comment: Make sure the directory exist. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

cl_dir = 'dir'

try:
    os.mkdir(cl_dir)
except OSError:
    pass  # os.mkdir will raise an exception if there's the directory. Ignore that.


with open(os.path.join(cl_dir, 'copy_success.txt'), 'w') as f:
    f.write('Copy done')
```

Comment: instead of 'w' shouldn't be 'w+' ?

Comment: I keep getting the error,the directory is present  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_build_artifacts.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "save_build_artifacts.py", line 72, in main
    with open('dir/copy_success.txt', 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dir/copy_success.txt'

Comment: @Elric, Why? Both will truncate the file.

Comment: @user3830867, Did you create the directory `cl_dir` instead of `dri`?

Comment: @falsetru sorry, you are right, I think I've read something wrong somewhere, just checked the docs! :]  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @falsetru - the dir name is dir and the directory exists

Comment: @falsetru - the file is not getting created

Comment: @user3830867, Come on, please show the code you used to create the file.

Comment: @user3830867 - the code is similar..am running this on windows7..the write(f.write) is not happening  ,no error when exeucting

Comment: @user3830867, Try to replace `'dir/copy_success.txt'` with `r'dir\copy_success.txt'` (NOTE: `r` is not a typo. It's there to mean raw string literal to make backslash literally denote backslash)

Comment: try:
        os.mkdir('cl_dir')
        print "CL_DIR2: " + cl_dir
        print cl_dir
    except OSError:
        pass  # os.mkdir will raise an exception if there's the directory. Ignore that.

    with open('cl_dir/copy_success.txt', 'w') as f:
        print "IN WITH"
        print "CL_DIR3: " + cl_dir
        print f
        f.write('Copy done')

Comment: @user3830867, So `cl_dir` is not literally `cl_dir`, but you want to make a directory with the value of `cl_dir` variable. Right? I updated the answer. Check it out.